# can't insert new row in html after inserting 3 items

Tags: c#, html

i want to show a page with 50 image. i want to show each 3 images in a row

what i did is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Images";
}
@{int i = 0;}
<table>
@foreach(var oneImage in Model){
    <a href="ShowOneImage/?imageID=@oneImage.ID">
                <img  class="rollover_img" src ="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) oneImage.image)" />
     </a>
    {i++;}
    if (i % 3 == 0) {     
        <p></p>
    }
}
</table>
```

however, i got this result:
[image]

please notice that the fouth image is not alighed in the second row although i made `<p></p>`

what am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to place links and paragraphs inside a table. That is invalid HTML, and no browser will generate elements like that. Different browsers will react in different ways, for example by creating table rows and table cells for you, or move elements outside the table.

Remove the table tags, or generate table rows and table cells for the content:

```
@{int i = 0;}
<table>
<tr>
@foreach(var oneImage in Model){
    <td><a href="ShowOneImage/?imageID=@oneImage.ID">
                <img  class="rollover_img" src ="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) oneImage.image)" />
     </a></td>
    {i++;}
    if (i % 3 == 0) {     
        </tr><tr>
    }
}
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {     
    <br/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag is meant for paragraphs. You should use the line break tag instead which is `<br />`